# XMLHttpRequest post function returned value (callback)

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, callback, xmlhttprequest

I want to make a callback function with returned value in `XMLHttpRequest`.
Ok so I can make it with `$.get` (example to show what I want to achieve).

```
$.get("/SomeFunction/", function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

and I want to make the same with `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/SomeFunction/", true);
xhr.send();
```

I tried many ways to get the `data` value in `XMLHttpRequest` but I dont know how to make such working callback function. Any tips?

Comment: So listen for the load event and call the function.

Comment: Ok, I tried it before, but I have no idea how to get the returned value?

Comment: Read MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if someone will need it in the future, I found a solution:

```
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
```